# how to highlight text after using istextpresent()

Tags: selenium-rc, highlight

how to highlight text after using istextpresent() in selenium RC.

> selenium.isTextPresent("Welcome");
>   After searching i want to highlight this text!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **highlight** command to make the particular element locator to highlight. It highlights the element in Yellow color.

```
selenium.highlight("//*[text()[contains(.,'Welcome')]]");
```

The above given Xpath is a sample one based on your input. Change it according to your HTML code.

**Suggestion:**

Selenium RC is a deprecated one and it has no further development. You can use WebDriver.